# How to compress sequential images eg from 5 second video?

Tags: image, video, compression

I have 50 images from a 5 seconds video (10 fps). How can I compress these images using spatial as well as temporal motion compensation into a single binary file? And later I want to recreate all the 50 images from this compressed file. (lossy is fine)

Comment: You have LOTS of options. But you should provide a few more details. As a baseline, what colorspace are the images? YUV or RGB (probably YUV)? Are they raw, uncompressed frames or already compressed as, e.g., JPEG? What platform (OS/CPU) do you need a solution for?